# whitespace trimmer plugin not working in console application

Tags: c#, console-application, image-resizing, imageresizer

I am using creative version

this is the code i am using for white space trimming

```
  ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(bmpStream, stream, new Instructions("trim.threshold=80&trim.percentpadding=0.5")));
```

I have included follwing dll

Aforge

Aforge.Imaging

Aforge.Math

ImageResizer.Plugins.WhitespaceTrimmer

and also installed

ImageResizer.Plugins.WhitespaceTrimmer

**its working in web application , but when i tried with console application there is no effect of white space trimming..**

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### .NET 4.0 doesn't load .dlls unless there is a static code reference.

Use the code installation method during startup instead of XML:

```
new WhitespaceTrimmer().Install(Config.Current).
```

Comment: which xml i am not using any xml explicitly of white space trimmer